# Assigning elements in a numeric matrix very slow in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am new to programming with Rcpp and C++ in general. So I hope this question is not too basic.

I am trying to write some code that will return a numeric matrix given some inputs. The code involves several loops, see below. Unfortunately it is extremely slow at present. However, if we run the code without assigning the computed numbers to the matrix, the program runs instantaneously. Similarly if we change the computed number slightly to exclude "tmp" below (see commented portion below), it runs instantaneously (see the commented out portion below).

Any tips on how to make this run more quickly are greatly appreciated! Apologies if this poorly written code offends you.

Code:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericMatrix llinftime(NumericMatrix infmat,
    NumericMatrix d,
    IntegerVector times,
    NumericVector theta,
    NumericVector pop) {

        int nrow = infmat.nrow();
        int ncol = infmat.ncol();

        NumericMatrix ll(nrow,ncol);

        int tmax;
        double pj;
        double lambdajt;
        double pi;
        double dij;
        double tmp;
        double pk;
        double djk;

        for (int j=0; j<nrow;j++){

            tmax = times[j];
            pj= log(pop[j]) * theta[0];

            for (int t=0;t<tmax;t++){

                lambdajt = 0;

                for (int i=0; i<nrow;i++){

                    if (i==j){
                        continue;
                    }

                    pi= log(pop[i]) * theta[1];
                    dij= log(d(i,j)) * theta[2];
                    tmp = 0;

                    for (int k=0; k<nrow;k++){

                        if (k==j){
                            continue;
                        }

                        pk = pow(pop[k],theta[1]);
                        djk = pow(d(j,k),theta[2]);
                        tmp += pk * djk;

                    }

                    lambdajt += exp(theta[4]+pi+pj+dij+log(tmp)*theta[3])*infmat(i,t);
                    //when we take tmp out it becomes instantaneous
                    //lambdajt +=exp(theta[2]+pi+pj+dij)*infmat(i,t);
                }

                ll(j,t)=lambdajt + exp(theta[5]);

            }
        }

        return ll;
}
```

Comment: Can you qualify _slow_?  Did you run a benchmark?

Comment: The full code takes approximately 198.16 seconds, while the code excluding the addition of the "tmp" takes 0.416 seconds. Perhaps this is normal, I am not familiar enough to tell! Thank you for your help. For reference temp is usually approximately 0.003, so a small number but not   unreasonably so.

Comment: It will be helpful if you include R code that runs the function llinftime